# Calculating Uptime From Date/Time In Python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm having problems calculating uptime using python because of the date/time format the API I'm using returns.

I'm pulling the time the service started from a json API using requests.
The server json API gives out the time/date in the iso1801 format.

Here is an example from the API: **2021-01-14T11:17:44-0800**

I need to take that date/time and calculate how many Minutes, Hours, Days and Months it has been since that example date/time above. The **-0800** offset will change from request to request because I'm checking multiple services in different locations.

I need to get a string output that looks something like this:

**3 Days, 6 Hours, 32 Minutes**

How would I go about doing this? Can someone write out an example? I have been coding in python for about 2 months now so I'm relatively new.

Comment: So, you need to parse data and time? Try `strptime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code snippet:

```
import datetime

def days_hours_minutes(td):
    return td.days, td.seconds//3600, (td.seconds//60)%60


dt = '2021-01-14T11:17:44-0800'
dt = dt[:-2] + ':' + dt[-2:]
dt_formatted = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(dt)
now = datetime.datetime.now(dt_formatted.tzinfo)

difference = days_hours_minutes(now - dt_formatted)
print(difference)
```

The example is timezone-aware. You will recieve time difference between the time API sends you and current time in the timezone to which API answer relates to.

**Warning:** method datetime.fromisoformat works only in **Python 3.7+**

Comment: This works for the server in my time zone (-0800) but I essentially need the "now" time to have the same offset as "dt" in your example. How would I go about replacing the offset in "now" to match the one in "dt"?

Comment: The example already does that in the line: ```now = datetime.datetime.now(dt_formatted.tzinfo)```